# API invoked failed: Custom headers present ; using Angular $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, angular-http, custom-headers

```
    (function(){
        app = angular.module('mySupport',['ngRoute']).controller('knwCenterCtrl');
        var config = {
            headers       : {
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.*********+json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
                'custom-header': '12345',
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Accept, custom-header'
            },
            responseType: 'json'
        };

        app.controller('knwCenterCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get("https://abcdefg.com/support/pub/navigation/products", config)
                .success(function(response)
                {
                    $scope.prodFam = response.productFamily;
    //                console.log($scope.mycases);
                });
        });
    })();
```

What am I missing in this get request? I was able to successfully invoke another APi from the same server using the same code. But for some reason, the code is not making any call to the server. Why is that? Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: Custom headers usually start with "X-", like `'X-Custom-Header': '12345',` Try that and also check the browser developer console network tab to ensure the header is being sent.

Comment: Hi, I checked on CDT but the request header have not changed. Even updated the custom headers with 'X-'. How can I go about this?